# Save load in gui application

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I try to make custom savefile for my GUI application.
In saving method I have something like this to save enabled status of all checkboxes.

```
enabledparams = [checkbox.isEnabled() for checkbox in self.tabParameters.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox)]
```

In loading method I should do this in backward sense, so to make enabled status from the saved

```
enabledparams
```

How to do this effectively in pythonic sense with minimum of code?
I have more of these cases for checked state of the boxes and also for a lot of spinboxes and textboxes.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

the QSettings module of Qt would be useful to you. It provides functionality to save and load application settings.

Comment: Not exactly as far as I can conclude (which is not so far :) ). I am trying to make a new saved file format, not ini file.